# Animating two layers in gganimate with different timesteps

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am using gganimate to overlay **animal tracking data** on top of **prey availability**, with both animated through time to show how animals' movements change as prey availability changes.

The **tracking dataset** consists of an

- a sumDur variable
- latitude and longitude
- at hourly intervals

The **prey dataset** consists of

- energy value
- latitude and longitude
- at weekly intervals

**Example of dataframes**

```
    head(Tracks)
          sumDur      lon2      lat                 gmt
30641  0.0000000 -170.2978 57.10774 2004-08-18 05:05:00
29380  0.0000000 -170.3264 57.05684 2004-08-18 06:00:00
29381 10.0833333 -170.3565 57.00376 2004-08-18 07:00:00
29382  3.0833333 -170.3859 56.95370 2004-08-18 08:00:00
29383  0.8333333 -170.4147 56.90687 2004-08-18 09:00:00
29384  2.6666667 -170.4429 56.86301 2004-08-18 10:00:00

 head(Prey)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  TotalEnergyM2   lat  lon2 gmt                
          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
1     0          50    160  2004-01-01 00:00:00
2     0          50    162. 2004-01-01 00:00:00
3     0.0000193  50    180. 2004-01-01 00:00:00
4     0          50.3 -151. 2004-01-01 00:00:00
5    38.3        53.9 -158  2004-01-01 00:00:00
6    31.4        53.9 -158. 2004-01-01 00:00:00
```

#### Goal

I have been able to successfully animate the tracking data on top of a static environment, and also animate the prey data without the tracking data.

**My problem lies in trying to create one animation of both - I get an animation but the timing of each animation is not correct even though I know the time overlaps.**

I believe this is being caused by the fact that the frame length of my time column (gmt) is not the same in each dataframe; in my tracking dataframe the timestep is one hour and in the prey dataframe the timestep is one week. Unfortunately I can not verify this because the prey dataframe is too large to replicate it to an hourly timestep. I have playing around with some of the different transitions (e.g. `transition_state`) but have not been successful and have not been able to find any solutions here or elsewhere.

Any help would be much appreciated and apologies ahead of time if I haven't provided enough information or the formatting is off - this is my first post.

#### Example code

```
plot <- ggplot(NULL) +
  geom_raster(data=Prey, aes(x=lon2, y=lat2, fill=TotalEnergyM2) +
  geom_point(data=Tracks, aes(x=lon2, y=lat2, size=sumDur)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()+
  transition_time(gmt)+
  ease_aes("linear")+ 
  labs(title="{frame_time}", x="Longitude", y="Latitude")

animate(plot)
```

The above code works perfectly if I comment out either geom_raster or geom_point so that I get separate animations, or if geom_raster is static. I have attached a link to two datafiles with fake data that work with the above code and reproduce the problems I am having [datafiles](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Lki9Ss8tZP_-yvEp33kxf0sbA_U1077a?usp=sharing).

Comment: What exactly is the `sumDur` variable?

Comment: It is the amount of time spent underwater in a given hour

Answer (score 0):

On my machine your code runs without a problem. If your `datetime` is properly formatted as Date `transition_time()` will fill all the gaps between your data points:

```
plot <- ggplot() + 
    geom_raster(data = Prey, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = energy)) +
    scale_fill_viridis_c() +
    geom_point(data = Tracks, aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = sumdur)) +
    transition_time(datetime) +
    ease_aes("linear") +
    labs(title="{frame_time}", x="Longitude", y="Latitude")

animate(plot, nframes = 100)
```

[image: 1]

#### Data

Comment: hmm..I have my datetime (called gmt) formatted as a POSIXct object but the times still don't seem to be matching up.